# Is there Django view decorator to check a condition that doesn't assume the input is a User?

Tags: python, django, python-decorators, django-permissions

I have a very simple Django decorator `my_decorator1` that looks like this:

```
def my_decorator_1(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_val = random.randint(0,1)
        return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

My Django APIView that looks like this:

```
class MyApiView(views.APIView):
    @what_decorator_goes_here
    @my_decorator_1 
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Blah Blah Blah. The rest is snipped out for brevity.
        """
```

Now I want a decorator to grant access to MyApiView ***iff*** self.my_val == 1. Otherwise it should give a permission denied error (403). How can I do it? I need it to replace `@what_decorator_goes_here`. This can't be that uncommon of a workflow.

Isn't there a prewritten django decorator I can use for this purpose? The two [**similar ones**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/) that I have seen are `@user_passes_test` and `@permission_required`. However neither of them operate on the `self` argument. The first one assumes the input is a `User` and the second one takes something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just return a `HttpResponseForbidden` response object:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

def what_decorator_goes_here(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def check_value(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if getattr(self, 'my_val', None) == 1:
            return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
    return check_value
```

Or more sophisticated:

```
def allow_if_view_value(attr_name, target_value):
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def check_value(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if getattr(self, attr_name, None) == target_value:
                return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
        return check_value
    return decorator

@allow_if_view_value('my_val', 1)
[...]
```

Albeit I must say, I am not too fond of using decorators to accomplish this instead of a generic view base class that dispatches requests accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be able to raise a PermissionDenied Exception from the decorator itself.

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def my_decorator_1(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_val = random.randint(0,1)
        if self.my_val == 1:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

I think thats how the decorators you've mentioned work. The Django request pipeline would then pick up the exception and handle it accordingly.